# how to consume XML in a REST WebService?

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I have an HTML form which submits an XML using a textarea field:

```
 <form  action="rest" method="POST">
   <textarea name="xml" rows="10" cols="30" ></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Invoke REST">
 </form>
```

Now i want to consume the XML in a REST Webservices (I'm using Java EE 7 and WildFly CR1).
I've tried using:

```
 @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
 public Response createItemFromXML(@FormParam("xml") Customer c) {

     ejb.addToList(c);

     return Response.ok("Created customer ").build();
```

}

Which leads to
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a constructor that takes a String param or a valueOf() or fromString() method for javax.ws.rs.FormParam("xml") on public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.sample.SimpleRESTService.createItemFromXML(com.sample.Customer) for basetype: com.sample.SimpleProperty

Do I have to use a Stream as form parameter (and convert manually to XML) or is there a simpler way to do it ?

EDIT:
I've tried as well with:

```
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public Response createPropertyFromXml(  Customer c) {

   ejb.addToList(c);
   return Response.ok("Created customer " + n).build(); 
 }
```

However the error is now: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: Cannot consume content type
Seems it cannot be converted from a form field to XML automatically....
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you should either set the `c` parameter as a String and then parse it in your `createItemFromXML` method, or your you could remove the `@FormParam` annotation on the method argument and use `JAXB` annotations on your `Customer` class. In that later case, the underlying JAX-RS implementation of Wildfly will convert the incoming XML request body into an instance  of `Customer`.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question, yet I'm still unable to convert automatically the incoming XML

Comment: Did you put `JAXB` annotations on the `Customer` type ? Also, you may want to unit test the JAXB marshalling/unmarshalling to be sure the XML <-> Customer works fine even outside of the Wildfly container.

Comment: I've added an @XMLRootElement on the top of the class. I think it's the minimal requirement for marshalling it.....

Comment: What content type does the client send ? Doh ! If it's a Form post, it's probably going to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. In that case, you have to retrieve the XML customer as an `@FormParam String`. Otherwise, you could use javascript (eg: jQuery) to submit a POST request with `application/json` (even if one element in the JSON document is XML)